# swift CoreData predicates

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspredicate

I'm adding CoreData to my app. Simple fetching is ok, but when i try to fetch data with predicate i get exception in `AppDelegate`.

```
func fetchWithPredicate(table: String, pred: String)->NSArray
{
    var appDel : AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate);
    var context : NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
    var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: table)
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: pred)//exception occurs on this string
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    var results: NSArray = NSArray()
    do{
        results = try context.executeFetchRequest(request)
    }

    catch{}

    return results
}
```

My predicate looks like this: `"routeFormed == %@"+route.identifier!` , where `route.identifier` is `String`. Should i add something to `AppDelegate` or to my entities? Also, i opened `.sqlite` file with sqlitebrowser, should i add predicates using visible names or the ones that i see in database`(i.e. "routeFormed" or "ZROUTEFORMED")?`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do *not* create predicates as strings, that is bound to fail in any but
trivial cases. Create the predicate as

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "routeFormed == %@", route.identifier)
```

or

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", "routeFormed", route.identifier)
```

and pass that to the fetch request. The keys in the predicate are the 
names of the entity properties as defined in the Core Data model
inspector.